# SSL rollout best practices?

Tags: ssl

Recently, we tried to make our artifactory https.

We followed the usual steps, placed it behind nginx and also had another nginx to help with http to https redirect [the usual return 301 and redirect].

As we were with http for a very long time, there are lots of scripts that uses http URL of our artifactory:

Starting from curls [without -L]
Ansible roles referring to http url
and terraform references to http url etc.
And all these are in several branches of our git repository. Once after SSL rollout even with redirect from http to https, most these failed obviously. Some of them are critical and we ended up switching back to http.

I am sure this is typical for almost all organization. I would like to understand, how do you guys plan such SSL rollouts and how issues like this tackled.

Any best practices around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to always start soft: Your approach was correct in *enabling* TLS, but you shouldn't *force* redirection from the start.

At this point, draw a line in the sand and tell everybody that any *new* scripts from this point on are to utilize TLS "or else".

The next step is to work your way through all old scripts that call the server using plain http, and gradually ensure they continue working using TLS. Obviously you don't want to just "grep-and-replace" in this step.

Finally, when you're sure all existing scripts are making TLS connections only, enforce the protocol by disabling plain HTTP, or by redirecting connections to HTTPS (if the clients are smart enough to understand the latter).

Comment: Yes we are doing similar but wanted to know any other best practices. Looks like this is the only way. Thanks.